# Image resizing in github README.md

Tags: html, css, github, markdown

I am adding images in Github's `readme.md` and trying to align them to the right side of the paragraph. Similar to the `float:right` property of the CSS.

I made it align to the paragraph's right side by containerizing the image into the paragraph.

**Here's how I did it**

```html
<p>
<img src="./assets/computer_illustration.jpg" height="200rm" align="right">

I am a full-stack web developer and currently learning many things...
</p>
```

#### Problem

There is a problem with the mobile version of the readme of the profile. I am attaching the image here. Tell me which property I should change to make it responsive for the mobile screens.

[image: Mobile Screen errored representation]

---

Comment: Here's my Github profile link if you want further details: [github](https://github.com/stack-dhruv)

Comment: did you try this https://gist.github.com/uupaa/f77d2bcf4dc7a294d109